# think of a Jira project as a table in a database

Tags: jira

A [tutorial](https://youtu.be/TsG3OWTDAFY?t=29) says

> You can think of the Jira project as a
>   table in a database.

If I think of a Jira project as a table in a database, what should I think of as the whole database?

Comment: That sounds very weird to start with. Just forget that comparison, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I think of a Jira project as a table in a database, what should I think of as the whole database?

Well, simple enough... all of your projects.

That being said, consider that 'All analogies are wrong. Some are useful.'

Unless you have a particular reason to be using these particular analogies, just ignore them.